# Can't open project created from Visual Studio Web Developer 2008 with Visual Studio Professional 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have several projects that opened just fine in Visual Studio Web Developer 2008 Express Edition, but can't be opened in VS 2008 Professional Edition! These projects are just .NET Framework 3.5 class libraries, and they are on the same machine.

**The error is "The project [myproject.csproj] cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by this installation.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon inspecting the project file, it seems like the project type have references to ASP.NET MVC 1. Installed MVC 1 solved the problem. Thanks!